# How to add and remove classes to navbar on scroll in Vue 3 Composition Api

Tags: scroll, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have been working to create graana.com clone with Vue 3 and Composition API syntax. I want add remove classes to navbar on scroll. If user scrolls downwards we should automatically add a class ("scrolled") to navbar to apply special styles and when screen is scrolled back to top ("scrolled") class is removed.

See example at https://www.graana.com/.

I want to copy their navbar behaviour using Vue 3 Composition API.

Can you help me out?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<header class="header" ref="headRef">
```

```js
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { onMounted } from "@vue/runtime-core";
setup(){
    const headRef = ref(null); // obtain the reference
    onMounted(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
            var curr = window.pageYOffset;

            // You can style header-bg for style purpose

            if (curr >= 100) {
                headRef.value.classList.add("header-bg");
            }else{
                headRef.value.classList.remove("header-bg");
            }
        });
    });
    return {
        headRef
    }

}
```